# Jquery datepicker, devise and rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've created additional fields on the Devise customer user registration page.  I was originally using the rails 5 date_field.  However, I've discovered this is not compatible with FF or IE.  I am now in the process of switching to jquery datepicker via the 'jquery-ui-rails' gem.

The gem is working, the calendar pops up and the field is filled with the correct date.  The jquery library requires the rails text_field to be used instead of the date_field.

The problem comes in when you try to save the field.  The form is obviously sending the field as a string, and rails doesn't know what to do with it so it just ignores it and doesn't save it in the database.  The database field is a DateTime.

What is the best/simplest way to convert this string to a date via the "Devise" user model?  Or is there a better approach?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a typo in my post above:  "customer user" should read "custom user".

Comment: Dates are passed as strings in the params, that's normal. If you go back to the date field it works (try it, it should be a quick change) ? Have you allowed this params through `devise_parameter_sanitizer`?

Comment: What do the sent parameters look like?

Comment: Yes, its in devise_parameter_sanitizer.  Changing it to a date_field causes the jquery calendar to not open.

Comment: They look perfect: "train_dt"=>"03/22/2017"

Comment: Could it be the dateFormat you are using in datepicker? Scratch that - your date looks fine.. Long shot, but you did permit the parameter? And, I see you did that as well..

Comment: Yep, done and done.  I had everything working in chrome without jquery just fine, but that version isn't compatible with FF or IE so I'm forced to use the jquery datepicker.

My original thought is that I have to do a type conversion somewhere, but devise is confusing things.

Comment: I don't think you should have to - I have exactly this datepicker working fine in an app (Rails 5 and as a textfield in the form), passed and saved with no conversion. I'm thinking it might be the devise element which is messing things up maybe?

Comment: Yea, that's my thought, but I'm not even sure where to look.  LOL